# Django rest framework - Delete model objects from HTML

Tags: python, html, django, web, django-rest-framework

So i'm developing an app using Django framework, and i need HTML forms to insert/delete and update data from the database. I was able to make the form to Update the data, but i can't seem to find any info on how to make a Create form and a delete button. 
I tried this, with no success:

**HTML**

```
<form action="{% url 'conta_details_html' conta.id %}" data-method="delete">

    <input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

Views:

```
class ContaDetailsHTML(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'conta_details.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = request.user
        conta = get_object_or_404(Conta, pk=pk,user=user)
        serializer = ContaDetailsSerializerHTML(conta)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'conta': conta})

    def delete(self,request,pk):
        """Deletes a transaccao"""
        user = request.user
        if not user.is_authenticated:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        conta = get_object_or_404(Conta, pk=pk, user=user)
        serializer = ContaDetailsSerializerHTML(conta,many=False)
        if conta:
            conta.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Maybe im not getting the syntax correct on the html, but the update form was pretty easy, like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'conta_details_html' conta.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

any idea ?

Edit:

**URL:**

```
url(r'^api/html/contas/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ContaDetailsHTML.as_view(), name='conta_details_html'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh even for delete is it's easy. You missed out on a few things here.
1. DELETE is a HTTP Verb, Your method field in the form can take one of this.

```
<form action="{% url 'conta_details_html' conta.id %}" data-method="delete" method="DELETE">

    <input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

2. In your delete view, you are trying to serialiaze but you don't need to.

   ```
   def delete(self, request, pk):
        """Deletes a transaccao"""
        user = request.user
        if not user.is_authenticated:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        conta = get_object_or_404(Conta, pk=pk, user=user)
        conta.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
   ```

Comment: is it that simple ? i tried that but when i press the button, nothing happens

Comment: You can try a API based DELETE request it should work. There are compatibility issues with form containing DELETE as action. Other wise you make endpoint api/html/contas/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete and write a POST handler with the same.

Comment: how do i do the api based delete request ?